# Make an App effects on organic search

Tags: seo, google-search, web-applications

At first, I'm sorry my English is not completely because not native English speaker.

We have an E-commerce shopping site that made responsive web design.
And we will make an App the contents in near the future.

If you download the App, use our service only via the App and our site traffic may a lot decrease.
Recently, the Google algo is very important not only page views and back link but also bounce rate, visit time, valuable contents and more.

We making access to only web so far.
The valuable access for SEO will divide to web and APP then.

I'm very worry that effects on organic search.

ex:
Before
web(mobile): 100% access
PV: 1,000,000

After
web(mobile): 50% access
PV: 500,000
App: 50% access
PV: 500,000

What's do you think?

Comment: The actual question part of this (towards the bottom) is not very clear. If you're just asking us how adding an app will affect your organic search stats, there's really no way for us to be able to answer that definitively. Questions here need to be answerable in a factual and definitive way, and those seeking opinions are considered off-topic. If you meant something else, then please clarify what your question is by editing it, and it will then be added back to the review queue for consideration to be reopened.